# The type or namespace name 'EventHandler' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml'

Tags: event-handling, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to build a Metro app using the Windows 8 SDK, but when I try to actually compile it using Visual Stuido I get this

```
The type or namespace name 'EventHandler' does not exist in the namespace 'Windows.UI.Xaml'
```

Keep in mind, I'm a total beginner, is this easy to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type EventHandler is not contained in that namespace. One of your ***using*** statements must reference "System" since that is where this type lives

OR

You can use the fully qualified name of the object, such as "System.EventHandler".

If you are doing something like "Windows.UI.Xaml.EventHandler" you would get that error OR if you only declared ONE using statement at the top of your file such as "using Window.UI.Xaml".

Without knowing more about or seeing your code, it's difficult to say with absolute certainty. If this doesn't resolve your problem, include your code.